# get key value pair from xml osx

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am new at xml parsing. I want to parse the bellow xml from which i want to extract album name i.e AlbumName
                Photos (albumname is Photos). Some one please help me with this. I am getting the xml path using nsopenpanel.

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Application Version</key>
    <string>9.4</string>
    <key>Archive Path</key>
    <string>/Users/betterlabs/Pictures/iPhoto Library.photolibrary</string>
    <key>ArchiveId</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>Major Version</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
    <key>Minor Version</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>List of Albums</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>AlbumId</key>
            <integer>4</integer>
            <key>AlbumName</key>
            <string>Photos</string>
            <key>Album Type</key>
            <string>99</string>
            <key>GUID</key>
            <string>allPhotosAlbum</string>
            <key>Master</key><true/>
            <key>KeyList</key>
            <array>
                <string>1</string>
                <string>5</string>
                <string>3</string>
                <string>7</string>
                <string>9</string>
                <string>27</string>
                <string>23</string>
                <string>25</string>
                <string>21</string>
                <string>19</string>
                <string>17</string>
                <string>15</string>
                <string>13</string>
                <string>11</string>
                <string>29</string>
                <string>33</string>
                <string>31</string>
            </array>
            <key>PhotoCount</key>
            <integer>17</integer>
        </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [XMLDictionary](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary). It will parse your data/string object and give you a usable NSDictionary.